# How to parse JSon data on iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

```
{"code":200,"msg":"","type":"DEFAULT",
"data{"thumbsId":209834,"thumbsKind":"UP","fbObjectId":null,"canPostFB":true,"thumbsupCnt":292,"episodeId":2491},
"errorDetails":null}
```

I want to get `thumbskind` value of data. My codes are as follows:

```
@property(nonatomic, assign) NSInteger code;
@property(nonatomic, copy) NSString *msg;
@property(nonatomic, copy) NSString *type;
@property(nonatomic, copy) NSString *details; 
@property(nonatomic, copy) NSDictionary *data;


 NSDictionary *obj = (NSDictionary *)sender;

self.code = [[obj objectForKey:@"code"] intValue];
self.msg = [obj valueForKeyPath:@"msg"];
self.type = [obj valueForKeyPath:@"type"];
self.data = [obj valueForKeyPath:@"data"];
self.details = [obj valueForKeyPath:@"errorDetails"];
```

I can get `code`, `type`, `msg` and so on.

But I cannot get values of `data`.
How can I get its values like `thumbsId`, `thumbsKind` and `thumbsupCnt`?

Comment: They are in the `data` dictionary.

Comment: Your json data is incorrect for one thing, Should be: {"code":200,"msg":"","type":"DEFAULT",
"data":{"thumbsId":209834,"thumbsKind":"UP","fbObjectId":null,"canPostFB":true,"thumbsupCnt":292,"episodeId":2491},
"errorDetails":null}

Comment: NSLog your `obj` variable and it will make a bit more sense.  `thumsId` is inside the "data" dictionary.  (But I hope that you simply mis-copied that JSON, since it's invalid.)

Comment: (`"data{"thumbsId":209834,` should be `"data":{"thumbsId":209834,`)

Answer (score 0):

data is a dictionary inside dictionary so Try this

```
@property(nonatomic, copy) NSString * thumbsId;
@property(nonatomic, copy) NSString * thumbsKind;  
. 
. 
.

NSDictionary *obj = (NSDictionary *)sender;
NSDictionary *dataDict = (NSDictionary *)  [obj objectForKey:@"data"]


self. thumbsKind = [dataDict valueForKeyPath:@"thumbsKind"]; 
self.thumbsId = [dataDict valueForKeyPath:@"thumbsId"];
. 
.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSInteger thumbsId = [[self.data objectForKey:@"thumbsId"] intValue];

NSString *thumbsKind = [self.data objectForKey:@"thumbsKind"];

......
```

Answer (score 0):

Your data is in wrong Json format

It should be this :

```
"data:{"thumbsId":209834,"thumbsKind":"UP","fbObjectId":null,"canPostFB":true,"thumbsupCnt":292,"episodeId":2491},
```

Instead of

```
"data{"thumbsId":209834,"thumbsKind":"UP","fbObjectId":null,"canPostFB":true,"thumbsupCnt":292,"episodeId":2491},
```

and then try

```
NSDictionary *dataDict = (NSDictionary *)  [obj objectForKey:@"data"]
self. thumbsKind = [dataDict valueForKeyPath:@"thumbsKind"]; 
self.thumbsId = [dataDict valueForKeyPath:@"thumbsId"];
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I changed my codes like you. But I cannot get thumbsKind and thumbsId. They have null value. Even though I checked json format, it doesn't get values in data field.

Comment: have you changed Json format as I told you ?   Try  "valueForKey" instead of "valueForKeyPath" in the above code.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
NSInteger thumbsId = [[obj valueForKeyPath:@"data.thumbsId"] intValue];
```

You can reduce your coding pain and save your time by using
[JSON Accelerator](http://nerdery.com/json-accelerator)